# ng-show only working when set to true from the beginning

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, ng-show, ng-map

I am creating a map-based application using the angularjs library ng-map and have encountered a rather strange bug.

I have the following code:

script.js

```
vm.showMarker = true //Boolean to toggle marker

vm.toggleMarker = function(){
 if(vm.map.getZoom()>=12){
  vm.showMarker = true;   
 } else {
  vm.showMarker = false;
 }
 $scope.$apply();
}
```

html

```
<ng-map on-zoom-changed="vm.toggleMarker()" zoom="9">

<custom-marker>
 <div ng-show="vm.showMarker">
 ...
 </div>
</custom-marker>

</ng-map>
```

The idea is that the marker should only be visible if the map is zoomed enough.

If `vm.showMarker` is set to true from the beginning like above, the marker is first visible when the page is loaded, it then dissapears when zooming until zoom is >= 12 as expected.

However if i set `vm.showMarker` to false so that it is not visible from the beginning, it does not become visible either when zooming in.

Any idea on what might be causing this behaviour?

Comment: Try to log `vm.map.getZoom()` results and you should see, where is the issue: `if` or `else` block is triggering.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `ng-if` instead:

```
<custom-marker ng-if="vm.showMarker">
```